# ext4fs can't find ext4 filesystem on mount

Tags: ubuntu-11.04, mount, ext4

I'm trying to mount an iso on my ubuntu 11.04 natty

when I

```
df - T
```

I get that ext4 is my filesystem

However when I try to mount the iso using the

```
mount -o loop -t ext4 ....
```

I get :

```
can't find ext 4 filesystem
```

Any solutions to that?

Thanks for your help

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com), [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com), or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 1):

In the mount command, the -t parameter specifies the type of the filesystem being mounted, not the place where the directory is where the new filesystem will be mounted onto.  You say that the filesystem you're about to mount is an ISO file.  So the type is probably iso9960.

This question really belongs on superuser or serverfault.